# R: melting data to long format for ggplot from cumulative data

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I have binned data with cumulative counts indicated for each bin. First two columns of the file in the example are variables which will be used later as aestetics variables in `ggplot()` functions. Next columns are some values (Sb, Ss) of two bins and their counts (integers Nb, Ns) for each row (generally, more than two bins can be present).

```
continent,location,Ns,Ss,Nb,Sb
Australia,forest,13,191.2,5,420
Australia,lagoon, 19,150,7,300
Europe,forest,13,95,10,215
Europe,lagoon,32,130,17,205
```

EDT
 I need to melt data into long format, glueing together two columns with Si ("sizes") and separately two columns with Ni ("numbers"). That is, there will be two new variables: "size" and "counts" from (Sb,Ss,Nb,Ns) (first two columns are kept intact):

```
continent,location,size,counts
Australia,forest,191.2,13
Australia,forest,420,5
Australia,lagoon,150,19
Australia,lagoon,300,7
Europe,forest,95,13
Europe,forest,215,10
Europe,lagoon,130,21
Europe,lagoon,205,17
```

Function `gather()` from `tidyr` package only yields "key" and "value" options, so it can only take all values from last four columns and label them one by one with corresponding letter (former variable name) Ss,Sb etc.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly have no clue what you actually want done, but converting data from wide to long can be done using the spread() and gather() commands of dplyr. A google should direct you.